# Idiomatic way to construct a SQL INSERT query in Python

Tags: python, sql, insert

I have a bit of code to insert some values in a table. It seems a bit clunky - is there a neater way?

words is a list of dictionaries, and the entries contain other fields which I don't want to insert.

```
    # add the list of words to the words table
    time_stamp = datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()
    sql = "INSERT INTO words (word, user_id, game_id, score, time_stamp) VALUES "
    vals = []
    for word in words:
        vals.append("('%s', %s, %s, %s, '%s')" %
                    (word['str'], user_id, game_id, word['score'], time_stamp))
    cur.execute(sql + ",".join(vals))
```

Comment: In addition to being clunky, your code is subject to a [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attack.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because suggestions for improvements to existing code are better served at http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I know it's not secure - escaping removed to show the core issue

Comment: Asked in codereview, thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can do simply this:

```
tupleOfValues = [ value1, value2, value3, value4, value5]
cur.execute("INSERT INTO words (word, user_id, game_id, score, time_stamp) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)", tupleOfValues)
```

or

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO words (word, user_id, game_id, score, time_stamp) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)", [ value1, value2, value3, value4, value5])
```